# Enzyme: Stateless Functional Component returns undefined props

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I have a SFC that I am testing using Enzyme shallow rendering. I am passing a style object with inline styles as props to this stateless component. However when I apply unit test to it, it returns undefined. I am not sure if that is okay as I understand that this component is just returning whatever is passed to it as props and as nothing is passed/rendered it is giving me undefined. Is there any workaround for this?

```
const LoginForm = ({ style, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div style={_.get(style, 'container')}>
        {inputFields}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

**Test:**

```
it('should apply styles to first div', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm style={{display: 'inline'}}/>);
        expect(wrapper.find('div').first().prop('style')).to.eql({display: 'inline'});
      });
```

Comment: Could you post the unit test code as well?

Comment: @MichaelParker Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of reasons for why this would fail.

First, it looks like you're using the Enzyme shallow wrapper API incorrectly.

If you want to get a specific prop from a shallow wrapper, you need to use `.props()` (in other words, you forgot the 's').

```
wrapper.find('div').first().props('style')
```

However, even with this correction, your test will still fail, because in your test, you're passing `{display: 'inline'}` as the `style` prop, but you're looking for a property called `container` in your implementation.  I assume you're using `lodash.get`, which [gets the value at the path of an object](https://lodash.com/docs#get).  Since the object you're supplying doesn't have a `container` property, the div's `style` prop will be equal to `{style: undefined}`, and the test will fail when trying to compare this to `{display: 'inline'}`

Comment: That was indeed the solution. I actually managed to figure it out but that's correct so I will mark this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: And one more thing, `.prop(key)` works as well. It's in the docs. https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.md

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that.  I wonder why it wasn't working for me when I copied your code and tried it out.  Thanks for the info though!